# iOS Afnetworking 2.0 AfSecurityPolicy.m showing an error while building the project

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I am following a tutorial at http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course for iOS AfNetworking. The tutorial follows the old version of AfNetworking, but I have managed to migrate it to the new AfNetworking (2.0). After following the JSON request I had no error. As soon as I hit the run button to run the app, I get the following error due to AFSecurityPolicy.m at two places.

"No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'firstObject'".

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Initially, the security framework was not included, so I included it in case the error was due to that. But, after adding SecurityFramework the error is still there.

Now I am kind of lost since I searched the web and didn't find any problem similar to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: same here, any luck!?

Comment: Ya, I think the solution was using XCode 5.0. I think AFNetworking 2.0  needs XCode 5.0 at least. I run the same project on Xcode 4.6 and I have the errors, while on Xcode 5.0 it runs fine. So, try that and let me know.

Comment: Now you need to use cocoapods.. I didn't found any other solution.. Check the [Starting guide with AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking) and this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12139/introduction-to-cocoapods) for better understanding

Comment: @mdhossain - I don't think anyone can read that error. You should include the text in your question. This ensures folks can read it; and future visitors can search it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[NSArray -firstObject]` is new to iOS 7, your target architecture is probably set too old. AFNetworking 2.0 only supports iOS 6 and iOS 7.

Comment: Well My project is built for iOS 6 +, still AFNetworking 2.0 did not work

Comment: Though I have solved it, as mentioned in my previous comment, I would accept this as an answer because this was the reason to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

From The Question It Seems that you Been using OSX foundation.framework rather that ios cocoa touch Foundation.framework
As in Osx console apps the NSArray dont have the property of first Object 
you can use the

array[0] for the instance if error still persist better switch to ios sdk for further use.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In order to get your old code running you need to use AFNetworking old version pod, that used to work properly.

For that you need to edit in your "Podfile" in TextEditor

change " pod 'AFNetworking' " to " pod 'AFNetworking','~> 1.3.1' " (you need to use your verison of AFNetworking that was working fine)

Then run "pod update" on terminal